# Xcode Menu of Buttons

Tags: xcode, button, collections, view, menu

I'm a complete newbie to Xcode and I'm trying to create my first app for my website: www.mathimation.co.uk

I'd like to create a menu of buttons similar to my website, which looks like the home screen of an iPhone/iPad. The buttons simply take you to another screen when clicked.

However I'm stuck! I've tried using buttons and labels within stacks, however I can't quite get the constraints/sizing correct. Everything moves or doesn't resize correctly on different devices. I've found tutorials that have worked for Image Views, but not Buttons which contain images. I've tried a Collection View, however I feel out of my depth with the coding and it then doesn't work.

If I were building a website, I would create a table, insert the images and text, then hyperlink to different pages. But this doesn't seem as simple!

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or know of any good tutorials to help?

Thank you so much!

Screenshots:

Menu on my website I am trying to create:

http://www.mathimation.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Mathimation-Menu.png

EDIT: I have had some success with Stacks, however am I now using too many?

http://www.mathimation.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Xcode-Menu-1.png

Comment: Could you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried?  Perhaps using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Is there a way of sharing the Xcode files? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Apple provides an excellent first-time app tutorial here: [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift): Jump Right In](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/) The tutorial demonstrates tables with images and text; how to move between views (pages); and, how to set constraints. It should be a perfect example for you to start with!

Comment: @leanne Thank you for your reply. I did look at this site, but I wanted a menu which is more like a grid - 3 columns and 3 rows, for example. Do you know if this can be done with tables?